# How to set maxViewMode in Bootstrap Datepicker (with JS Fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a simple installation of [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker):

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {minViewMode: "days", maxViewMode: "days"});
```

I am trying to disable the user's ability to switch to month view (achieved by clicking on the month title). I have set `maxViewMode` to `days` as per the [docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#maxviewmode), but it doesn't work.

**[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/m2bak1fc/)**.

Where am I going wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap Datepicker version 1.4.0. Option `maxViewMode` is added in version 1.5.0 (not released yet).

[Official docs for version 1.4.0](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/options.html)